# My Css are overriden by Bootstrap in magento

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, magento

**> bootstrap css always override my css**

**local.xml**

```
   <reference name="head">
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap.min.css</name></action>
       <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/negi.css</name></action>
```

after including bootstrap my margin-padding are override automatically

Comment: Please show us exact code.

Comment: It is likely that bootstrap is being imported AFTER your style sheet

Comment: no if i call bootstrap before my style sheet then same result

Comment: can anybody tell me what's going wrong???

Comment: @Rahul negi, you should provide more detailed information to avoid downvotes but in fairness I don't think you deserved 3 downvotes for this question. Others should ask for more details before down voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be due to a number of things, first check  in your browser inspector to see exactly what BootStrap rule is overriding yours, is it using the `!important` keyword? Does it have a greater [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than your css rule? You may just have to write your css rule with greater specificity or the `!important` key word.

Next check what order are your css files loaded on the page? Check the **view source**(ctrl U) in your browser to be sure, your layout xml may have a conflict i.e. another layout file effecting the order, try this to fix that cause:

```
<reference name="head"> 
  <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap.min.css</name></action>
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap.min.css</name></action>
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/negi.css</name></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get your question, but here's an example overriding some bootstrap properties.

```css
div.container > div.row > div[class*="col-"]{
  background-color: #EEE;  
  border-radius: 4px;
}
div[class*="custom-col"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px; 
  padding: 2px;  
}
.well.custom {
    min-height: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #f5f500;
    border: 1px dotted #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>   
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row well">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">Column One</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">Column Two</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">Column Three</div>
   </div>    
   <div class="row well custom">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 custom-col-1">Column One</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 custom-col-2">Column Two</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 custom-col-3">Column Three</div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```